# Is there a simple library for C++ to draw to the screen?

Tags: c++, graphics

I'm just starting out in C++ programming and I want to try creating a space invaders clone in C++, I want to avoid using game libraries and things that would solve a lot of the problems (like game loop and vector maths etc) so I can tackle these myself, but, I have no idea how to begin drawing things to a screen.

I was wondering if there's a good library I should use to simply allow myself to draw lines or graphics to the screen or whether I can do this without the use of a library?

I'd appreciate any advice,

Thanks.

Comment: C++ can't do *anything* without a library. It makes very few assumptions about the machine it will be running on; in particular it doesn't assume it has any graphics capability at all.

Comment: This might be a case where iterative development is a better approach, starting out with a library which solves most of the problems for you, just to get a minimal game functioning, then slowly replacing each piece provided by the library with something you wrote yourself.  The down side is that your final structure will be quite similar to the design of the original library, but the upside is you will always have a functional program to go back to.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I recommend either Allegro or SDL, even though they are mostly 2D:

Allegro:
http://alleg.sourceforge.net/

SDL:
http://www.libsdl.org/

Comment: I've used both and they are both pretty easy to use if you know C++.

Comment: This is the best book for using Allegro to make games:
http://www.amazon.com/Game-Programming-All-Jonathan-Harbour/dp/1598632892/ref=ntt_at_ep_dpi_1

Comment: There's Dear ImGui now also.

Answer (score 5):

Check out [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/).

Answer (score 5):

I would check [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org) or [Allegro](http://www.talula.demon.co.uk/allegro/)

Answer (score 3):

I guess SDL is the simple library you're looking for. If you want you can work pretty much with the screen as a framebuffer where you modify pixel by pixel if you really want. It's a C library, but it's quite object oriented, so it's nice to work with in C++ as well.

Answer (score 2):

[PixelToaster](http://code.google.com/p/pixeltoaster/) (was OpenPTC/TinyPTC) is one of my favorites. It's fairly minimalistic and very easy to get started with.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of simple libraries. SDL and Allegro have gotten a lot of mentions already, but there are several others as well:

- OpenGL
- DirectX (yes, yes, I know, not "simple," but certainly gets the job done)
- [Cairo](http://annarchy.cairographics.org/) (for vector drawing)
- [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/) (an SDL-alike that has some drawing primitives)
- [GGI](http://www.ggi-project.org/)
- [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/products/) (which does a lot more than widgets and is highly modular)
- [DirectFB](http://www.directfb.org/) (which works without a host GUI like X.org)

And many others I'll be kicking myself for forgetting.

Comment: OpenGL is very low-level though, I'm not sure a guy that just wants to make a game wants to look through all that. SDL already runs on OpenGL, so I guess that could be a substitute.

Also, DirectX is a Windows-only platform, OpenGL is cross-platform. :)

Comment: @Johannes Jensen: SDL doesn't run *on* OpenGL, as far as I know. It *facilitates* OpenGL, but doesn't actually *use* it. Indeed, unless there has been some major change to the API I'm unaware of, it doesn't even have drawing primitives. It just gives you a raster surface to draw on. I'd even say SDL is *lower*-level than OpenGL for that reason. (And I mention DirectX only for completeness.)

Comment: SDL can make OpenGL contexts, but pure SDL uses a (very slow) software renderer.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it be more interesting to do it by printing 80x?? ascii characters on the screen every .x seconds?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, starting right away with a GUI library like wxWidgets (www.wxwidgets.org) is a good idea because they are often platform-independent and provide good drawing mechanisms -- plus all that other GUI stuff you might find useful later on.